# Map<String,?> in Android Studio

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get strings from SharedPreferences in Android Studio. But I get two unexpected errors.
Here is my code:

```
Map<String,?> keys = sharedpreferences.getAll();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : keys.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

I get "cannot resolve symbol 'entrySet'" and "unexpected token" for "for"
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-loop, replace `<String, String>` by `<String, ?>` to resolve the error.

```
Map<String,?> keys = sharedpreferences.getAll();

for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

---

And if you only want the `String` objects:

```
Map<String,?> keys = sharedpreferences.getAll();

for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```